# How do I upload a photo without it being a type="file"?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a selenium program that will let me log into my Instagram account and upload a photo from a folder as my profile picture.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

def changePhoto():
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/")

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class=\'sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     \']")\
        .send_keys("This is where I put the directory for the photo I want to upload")

def instaProfile(un, pw):
    driver.get("https://instagram.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\'username\']")\
        .send_keys(un)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\'password\']")\
        .send_keys(pw)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")\
        .click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class=\'_6q-tv\']")\
        .click()
    driver.get("https://instagram.com/" + un.lower() + "/")

username = "DummyUsername"
password = "DummyPassword"

instaProfile(username, password)
changePhoto()
```

So while I believe this would usually work, the issue here is that the button that Instagram has to do this isn't listed as a file upload, so the send_keys can't pass a directory through.

I have tried using a .click() to open it, then use driver.window_handles[], but that doesn't seem to recognize the file selection window as an actual window and says that driver.window_handles[1] isn't real

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is helpful but in Java for uploading files with Selenium we use Robot class, because the dialog box that it is opened is not part of the browser. That is why you can't find any selector for it and it is not a window handle as it is not part of browser.